# Flutter cast RenderObject to RenderBox

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, casting, render

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5DkShqvIAU) creating a `DropDown`. But I can not copy his code because `Flutter 2.0` is forbidding it because  of these lines:

```
  void findDropdownData() {
    RenderBox renderBox = actionKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()!;
    height = renderBox.size.height;
    width = renderBox.size.width;
    Offset? offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    xPosition = offset!.dx;
    yPosition = offset.dy;
  }
```

As you can see I tried do add some `!` and `?` but it is still not working. The main issue is that `findRenderObject` returns `RenderObject` but I need it to be a `RenderBox`... Any idea what's wrong here? Can not figure it out..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought:

simply use `as` like this:

```
RenderBox renderBox =
    actionKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes `actionkey` may shows error, so simply use *as*

```
RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

u can also add more safety check, based on @Chris's

```
    RenderObject? obj = context.findRenderObject();
    if (obj == null) {
        return;
    }
    bool isBox = obj is RenderBox;
    if (isBox == false) {
        return;
    }
    RenderBox box = obj as RenderBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also resolve it like this

```
final renderBox = actionKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).